# How to create a chrome extension to change the default tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a chrome extension which changes my default tab in chrome browser.

Inside the page I will put my favorite websites, which I think I can handle using HTML + CSS. My difficult part is how to make it become a chrome extension because I have never done it before.

Can anyone give me some basic steps which I could start with?

Comment: If you don't want to distribute it, you can simply write an html file, and on your chrome parameters, add it in the tabs to open on startup ?

Comment: Thank you @ValentinO., yes I can do it that way. But I still would like to learn how to create an extension like that which I can add more functions later.

Comment: that's why I simply added a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: @Paulie_D As much as I agree with you on doing own research (and can be short-tempered at dealing with repeated questions that show none of that), _any_ problem can be solved given enough own research - but it's not always the best strategy. That's where SO is supposed to come in - for example, OP did not know that the page in question is called "New Tab page" as opposed to "default tab", and we're supposed to help with that. This is most certainly _not_ a question that is in the "gimmie teh codez" category - it explicitly asks for _basic steps_, not a complete solution.

Comment: @Xan ...and supplying *basic steps* is not the function of SO. We're not a tutorial site. That what **additional research** is all about. Check the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Paulie_D I did. And I have a dissenting opinion. Sometimes own research needs to be _steered_. More often than not, for example, my answers contain conceptual explanations + documentation links rather than complete code examples. Looking at your close reason: it's not a question _seeking debugging help_, so I disagree. Is it a too-broad question? Despite how it looks, as a top-3 user in the tag I can assure it's a reasonably-scoped question. It can be answered in a few paragraphs. It's a question (clumsily) seeking a _high-level overview_, and I argue it has its place on SO.

Comment: @Xan (and Paulie_D) The [original documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) is in the top results (#1 without this question) of a Google search when searching for the [original Question Title](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+create+a+chrome+extension+to+change+default+tab). IMO, any such Question, by definition, means the OP did not do enough of their own research. OP's are supposed to at least *attempt* to find an answer on their own. A question to which an answer can be found easily by searching for *just* the question title is, IMO, bad (should be down-voted).

Comment: @Paulie_D (and Xan). It is possible (perhaps likely) the Google title-search results we get now (e.g. after an answer has been posted with a link to the documentation) may be different than what the OP saw when writing the question. However, the results should have at least included that page. As to being off-topic, I agree it is clearly not a debugging question. Xan, as you mentioned, the other stock close reasons don't really apply. On the other hand, it is basically asking for a (short) tutorial (which SO is not). Arguably, it could be a dup of a "How do I write an extension" question.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will write more specific questions next time. Appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for what's called [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

An extension can declare that it supplies a new `newtab` page. Here's a strictly minimal manifest for it:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My awesome New Tab override",
  "version": "1.0",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  }
}
```

Then you can use this manifest, together with a `newtab.html` and required resources, to make a simple extension.

There are many guides past that point; you can see the [Learn Basics](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) part of the official docs. Remember you can always ask a new question here if you run into *specific* implementation questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it means a lot to me. I banged around for a while with finding a similar solution. Once again for me, it came down to not asking the right question sooner.